# OpenVPN for Macosx got .ovpn from Windows user but need own key and crt files?

Tags: mac-osx-server, osx-yosemite

Ok, I don't know if this is something I need to setup on my computer or if this is something that the client needs to give me.  I believe a .key file is private, however, I seem to be having issues with this.

Basically, I need to access a Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection, but before I can do this I need to run OpenVPN (which is not a program that is available for MacOSX, only for Windows PCs).  So, after some research I discovered Tunnelblick is the next best thing on MacOSX computers.  However, the .ovpn file (that I received from the client) does not install on Tunnelblick due to wrong `.crt` and `.key` file locations (which are on the clients Windows Computer), but Tunnelblick also needs a `ca` file I believe.  I don't know where I am supposed to get these files from.  Do I generate them myself, or is this something that the client should be giving me?  I tried generating these files myself (crt and key), but I keep getting errors, so not sure what to do here.

Tried creating these files via this page here:  http://brianflove.com/2014/12/01/self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-mac-yosemite/

But Tunnelblick is not connecting when adding the crt and key files in the .ovpn file.

Figured I'd ask on here first before I spend days researching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ovpn` file should contain `ca` certificates, openvpn `crt` and `private key`. All this information should be received from openvpn provider.

Comment: So the client should send me the ca, crt, and key files than right?

Comment: @SolomonClosson, yes you're right.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I wasn't sure of this, but needed to be sure.